# Am I missing something, or referencing an activity in the viewModel does not cause problems if I do it in a lifecycle-conscious way

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, activity-lifecycle

I am writing an app for fun. The app launches, does some networking stuff and shows its progress in the MainActivity.
I decided to do the networking stuff in the viewModel so it could survive activity-lifecycle-misery. But in order the show the progress on the UI I need a reference to the activity in the model to call functions on it, but it is considered a fatal mistake beacuse of the lifecycle-misery :D.

So, I've been thinking. If the reference variable in my viewModel is constantly changing as activities come and go and it always points to the current activity, then it should be alright.

So I need to declare a nullable, reassignable activity variable

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var activity: MainActivity? = null
}
```

The solution, when the activity is created it assigns itself the variable. And when it is destroyed, it clears it with null. (This is similar to subscribing.)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Initialization
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // My viewModel solution
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
        viewModel.activity = this
}

override fun onDestroy() {
        viewModel.activity = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

If I am right this creates no leaks or runtime errors whatsoever, my networking stuff survives the activity's death and I can conveniently call functions on the currently alive activity.

My Question is: Am I right?

Note: For avoiding thread-misery I use coroutines (with IO dispatchers) in the viewModelScope for networking stuff and call the activity's functions with the Main dispatchers.

Comment: `But in order the show the progress on the UI I need a reference to the activity in the model to call functions on it` well this definitely isn't true, you most definitely don't _need_ a reference to an activity to do this

Comment: You should use livedata to avoid referencing activity or fragment in your viewModel.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata